# Does UIImagePickerController have to have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Does the UIImagePickerController delegate have to be a view controller embedded in a navigation controller?  Just asking because the view controller that I want the user to be able to select photos from is not currently in one, and I manually input a navigation bar with bar button items.  It would just be annoying to have to relink and re-paste the code of those buttons into new ones, and slightly worrying about how I might have to change my code with segues and whatnot.  If I just give the delegate of the UIImagePickerController a UINavigationControllerDelegate up top, will that work, or must I then embed the view controller in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be embedded in a `UINavigationController`. You could just conform the `UIViewController` sub-class to the protocols `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and it will work just fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @objc func showImagePicker() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        // do other stuff...
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
}
```